# Internal Server Error 500 using Ajax in Laravel blade using POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, internal-server-error

I have a button in my blade:

```
<button id="save-adjuster" style="color:black" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Save Result</button>
```

And I have the following JavaScript to process it via Ajax:

```
<script>
                $( "#save-adjuster" ).click(function() {
                        $.ajax({
                                url: '{{ Request::url() }}/save-adjuster',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {
                                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                                        "splitname": "{!! $split_name !!}",
                                        "adjusting_payment": "{!! ($adjusting_amount/2) !!}"
                                }, 
                                success: function (result) {
                                        alert("Saved", "This split scenario's adjusting payment amount has been saved", "success")
                                },
                                error: function (result) {
                                        alert({
                                title: "Oops",
                                text: "We ran into an issue trying to save this item",
                                icon: "error",
                                button: "Dismiss",
                                })
                                }
                                });  
                        });
                </script>
```

Viewing this as page source shows the "data" parameters correctly formed. I'm getting a `jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 POST 500 (Internal Server Error)` error with a dialog box that says

```
localhost:8080 says [object Object]
```

It looks like the ajax is formed correctly but this never reaches the controller (below) as the dd() in my controller never fires. My Apache error logs don't show anything at all - this is not getting recorded in logs even though it's clearly a server error.

I've read pretty much every reference available on such a Laravel Ajax error and almost everything refers to missing the CSRF token, but I have that and the Chrome inspector and console show a well-formed token.

FWIW, here's my route:

```
Route::post('tax-split-scenario/{split_name}/save-adjuster', 'GenerateScenarioController@storeAdjuster')->middleware('auth');
```

and here's my controller:

```
public function storeAdjuster(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->input('splitname'));

    //Store splt adjuster amount
    $update_split = SplitScenarioAdjustment::where('split_scenario_name', '=', $request->splitname, 'and')->where('created_by_id', '=', Auth::id())->first();
    $update_split->adjusting_payment = $request->adjusting_payment;
    $update_split->save();


    return redirect()->route('named-split-scenario', [$split_name]);
}
```

I'm running Laravel 5.5 and XAMPP on Windows 10.

Any and all suggestions are very welcome. I have trolled through every suggested posting here and elsewhere on the web to no avail and have ground to a halt - thanks in advance for any assistance.

::ADDED CONSOLE OUTPUT::

```
jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 POST http://localhost:8080/DS_dev_01/public/tax-split-scenario/Gregs/save-adjuster 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ Gregs:2250
dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
y.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
Gregs:2263 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.error (Gregs:2263)
    at l (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6)
error @ Gregs:2263
l @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4
fireWith @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4
k @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
load (async)
send @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ Gregs:2250
dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
y.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/DS_dev_01/public/tax-split-scenario/Gregs/save-adjuster".
send @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ Gregs:2250
dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
y.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
```

When I change the error function to (because it was showing "data" above as undefined):

```
                        error: function (data, url) {
                                console.log(data);
                                console.log(url);
                                alert({
                        title: "Oops",
                        text: "We ran into an issue trying to save this item",
                        icon: "error",
                        button: "Dismiss",
                        })
```

I get a lot of nested recursive output in the console (too big to post here) but nothing I can see to indicate what the issue is other than my URL "failed to load"

Also, changing my route to see if the URL being called was somehow wrong:

```
Route::post('tax-split-scenario/{split_name}/save-equalizer',function()
    {return 'Success, the route from Ajax is working';
    });
```

gets no response, confirming that I'm not getting that far. This apparently fails in the blade JavaScript.

// UPDATE //

Looks like the error function code for the alert box was an issue. I changed the script code to:

```
        <script>
        $( "#save-adjuster" ).click(function() {
                console.log('{{$split_name}}');
                $.ajax({
                        url: '{{ Request::url() }}/save-adjuster',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                                "_method": 'POST',
                                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                                "splitname": '{!! $split_name !!}',
                                "adjusting_payment": 1000
                        }, 
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                                //console.log(data);
                                alert("Saved", "This amount has been saved", "success")

                        },
                        error: function (data, url) {
                                //console.log(data);
                                //console.log(url);
                                alert("We ran into an issue trying to save this item")
                        }

                        });  
                });
        </script>
```

and the server error goes away, but now I get this in the console:

```
Gregs
jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/DS_dev_01/public/tax-split-scenario/Gregs/save-adjuster".
send @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ Gregs:2251
dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
y.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 [Violation] 'load' handler took 3445ms
```

Ignore the time reported at the end, that's the time before I click the alert box. I also hard-coded the data parameter "adjusting_payment".

Now my error alert fires but noting to tell me what's the issue.

Comment: Please show us your full form. Also, create your data object and do a `console.log(data)` and `console.log(url)` before your `ajax` call. Your data object should include the `_token`, `splitname` and `adjusting_payment`.

Comment: What does your chrome inspector's network tab shows ? (click on the request and show as the response). Also check laravel log.

Comment: there's probably useful information about what the "internal sever error" actually is in the server logs - that's what I'd be looking at ... the logs on the **server** regarding the internal **server** error

Comment: @Chukwuemeka There's really nothing more to the code. I'm not enclosing the button in a form element, it's just the button with the JavaScript onClick response. I did add the console log commands and got the following:

Comment: @Jaromanda X  As mentioned in the OP the server logs are not showing this at all. Network output added to the post.

Comment: Ur `url` is wrong. It doesn't match what you have defined in your `route` file. Replace it with `'/tax-split-scenario/Gregs/save-adjuster'` and try again.

Comment: `the server logs are not showing this at all` - which server logs are you looking at